# How to split a string by space and newline in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm a beginner in Golang and I want to split a multiline text terminated by the EOF indicator, and I want to do it by the space and the presence of new lines ( since the user is gonna press "enter" a lot ).

Any idea of how?

Answer (score 4):

Use strings.Fields

`words := strings.Fields(someString)`

See example in [The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Yew9PIIubR8)